# tinymce-knockout-binding not showing formatting

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, tinymce

I'm trying to get the [tinymce-knockout-binding](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding/) plugin by [michaelpapworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955675/michaelpapworth) (an awesome plugin by the way).  The problem that I'm having is that I'm trying to bind an editor with some pre-existing html markup, but it's showing the tags instead of showing it formatted.

Here's a jsfiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rsparkyc/MT7cf/2/

My view model is as follows:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.wysiwygOptions = {
        forced_root_block: false
    };


    self.selectedText = 
      ko.observable('I want this<br /><h1>to show formatting</h1>In the editor');
}
```

and I'm binding to the observable like this:

```
<div class="editableArea" 
     data-bind="wysiwyg: selectedText, wysiwygConfig: wysiwygOptions"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Line 14 of the plugin

```
e(i).text(s()());
```

This assumes you are posting plain text... You can change this line to

```
e(i).html(s()());
```

and it will correctly format.. I believe that the setContent function used on the update already accommodates HTML so should not need further upgrades

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your binding with a `text` instead of a `html`:

```
e(i).html(s()());
```

Corrected **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MT7cf/3/)**